# What is the best way to make slight feature changes to imported unity assets?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender

I found a pack of unity assets (these [3D characters with built-in animations](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/creatures/monsters-ultimate-pack-02-cute-series-179083)) that serves my purposes very well, but I want make slight feature changes to some of them. For example, I would want to change the color of some, maybe add a horn or other utensil, make the tail longer etc. I would like these changes to impact the animations minimally. I am wondering about what is the best workflow for this.

I looked into importing the .fbx files into Blender to make such featural changes, but the animations are not retained in Blender (this seems to inevitable according to [some](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/cq98ca/how_to_export_character_with_animation_from_unity/)?). In general, most information is about workflows going from Blender to Unity, rather than the other way. I am thinking of importing the .fbx files into Blender regardless, without the animations, changing some features, and then importing back into Unity, hoping that the Unity animations can snap back onto the modified creature.

Since I am a beginner with both Unity and Blender, I wanted to check whether this is has a chance to work or whether there are better alternatives. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unity animation if done using the main tool is probably just animating properties of the model/objects that are exposed to Unity's serialized interface, e.g. color, position, etc. So, either they animated the model hierarchy inside Unity (sounds unlikely), in which case the animation is part of an animation clip, or they did it in Blender, in which case the animation should be part of the fbx.

You can try an application like [Fbx Review](https://apps.autodesk.com/MAYA/en/Detail/Index?id=6979630331069053932&appLang=en&os=Win64) to view the fbx file and see if it includes the animation.

### Unity Animation

Unity binds its animation streams with Transform/GameObject names. As long as you don't modify the hierarchy of the model, you should be able to modify it in blender like you want and later import into Unity.

### Fbx Animation

Simply import into Blender, and make any changes that don't break the animations.

### Alternative

If you really must, you can modify the imported mesh inside the Unity Editor. There's a few tools available for this in the assetstore.

### Last Bet

Simply email the asset seller and ask them what the best way to proceed would be. For a 150$, they will probably be willing to provide this amount of support.